# Issue with CREATE UPDATE TABLE in MSSQL with db_ddladmin permission

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms, create-table, alter-table

I can't `Update` or `Create` tables within Visual Studio 2022 and SSMS, till now I was able to do everything, I didn't change any users etc. just from one minute to the other, the button `Update` has been disabled.

[image]

[image]

I have checked the permissions assigned to that user and it was checked all required permissions for that, see below

[image]

I have contacted the company hosting the server, but they cant see any issues on it, and I'm lost.

Comment: Are you able to run the DDL in a query window without errors? Personally, I suggest one use T-SQL instead of the SSMS designers, which tend to be buggy.

Comment: To reiterate what @DanGuzman said: Try running the `CREATE TABLE ....` script directly from a new query window. If this fails, you will get an actual SQL Server error. The error you are getting now is generated by Visual Studio and may not be accurate.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I tried running in T-SQL, and Yes! it works! so its just a bug from visual studio?

Comment: The message from the SSMS designer looks like the intent is a warning rather than an error based on a cursory permission check of memberships of the roles listed in the message. My opinion is SSMS should still enable the Update button in this case and let you proceed at your own risk. The consensus among experienced DBAs is one should avoid the SSMS designers and use T-SQL directly. You might still use designers to help generate the DDL. if you need a crutch.

Comment: No, the Update button is disabled in SSMS and in VS as you can see in the first image I posted.